# How do I get the crash rate for an app out of Firebase programmatically?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

We have several iOS and Android apps using Crashlytics. For internal metrics and dashboards, I'd like to get the crash rate (number of crashes / number of sessions) out of Google Firebase programmatically preferably through their HTTP API. How do I do that ?

Comment: Do you mean Crashlytics instead of Firebase Crash Reporting (which has been fully deprecated)?

Comment: Yes, Crashlytics.

Comment: Have you developed this tool? Is this open source? I am trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no programmatic API, but you can [export data to BigQuery](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/exporting-crashlytics-data-to-bigquery.html) and do what you want with it from there

Comment: That's a viable way but I also need to find the number of sessions or users so I can calculate a crash rate - percentage of sessions with crashes. I can get that from Google Analytics - however; I think it's weird that Google does not provide a simple API for this.

Comment: You can always file a feature request.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features