# How to get the percentage of crash free users programmatically from Firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-play, app-store-connect

We regularly track the crash free users percentage on our system (for both our iOS/Android apps) on Firebase. However I would like to get this information programmatically if possible (from Firebase or any other source that shares this, such as iTunes connect or Google Play etc).

[image]

Comment: Might be helpful for you please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55046279/how-do-i-get-the-crash-rate-for-an-app-out-of-firebase-programmatically

Answer (score -1):

Have a look into this tutorial:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export

Its basically very straight forward, you export data from crashlytics into BigQuery, then you do whatever query you want